# Embedded C: Can I pass members of a static struct to function in another file, IF a pointer to the member is passed by a fn in the same file

Tags: c, pointers, static

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {

   uint8_t var_1;
   uint8_t var_2;

}TYPE_struct_variables;

static TYPE_struct_variables variables;
```

For argument sake, I want to pass one of the members in this struct down another layer towards the metal. For this example, this is a data struct for an external device and I want to pass the member '`variables->var_1`' / '`variables.var_1`' to the usart interface of a host micro-controller. HOWEVER, I still want to restrict access to this struct for all functions outside this file. Would it work to send a pointer to this member if that pointer was sent by a fn in the same file as the struct?

Or would the program crash upon realizing it's a pointer inside a 'restricted' space?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from it, but passing around pointers to static members does however almost certainly mean that your program design is bad.

Comment: Usually I would agree with you, but in this case it's about making an exception to the rule. This is for an input buffer for an external device, which I pass to the host's usart. I could just as easily put this one member as a standalone array and it would mean doing basically the exact same thing.

Comment: Starting to sound like more than just bad design. Why doesn't the UART handle its own buffer? How do you solve re-entrancy if the UART driver doesn't "own" the memory?

Comment: It has the pointer to the memory and this isn't an interrupt driven design.

Comment: If you're interested to know more, I'll tag you when I release the design manifesto next week :)

Comment: Ok but then you have a tight coupling between the UART protocol pace and the real-time performance of your program. That's ok if you have a real-time spec for how slow the background program is allowed to be.

Comment: How would one go about decoupling that? I figured that the UART will take as long as it does and then return.

Comment: By using interrupts/DMA :) Otherwise if you only use polling, you have to do so frequently enough to never get an overrun of the UART rx buffer. Unless you are fine with losing packages, just discard the lost one.

Comment: Yeh so in this design there is an interface function that loops through a set number of iterations, each iteration calling the actual read/write uart fn, which writes once and then returns. I don't know how to send a message but I would love to have your input on this design. Like I said, I'm gonna open the whole thing up with some examples. It's mainly about decoupling HALs using a middleware of generic callback functions :) it's mainly aimed at RTOS dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C by itself doesn't know anything about restricted space in RAM. If you hide a variable as static it only won't get external linkage. That means it won't have a symbol outside of its compilation unit that you can reference to but it will have a regular address in the RAM or ROM (if you architecture supports that and the variable is constant) and that address is accessible for everybody.

Or in short: You can pass pointers to static variables in the same way as you can pass pointer to other variables or locations in RAM.

Comment: Yeh I figured as much re:knowledge about RAM, but thanks for clarifying that about linkage. Also: this is huge news, thank you so much. :)